# Determine if the request comes from a new user

Tags: php, forms, security

Let's say you have a form. And you don't want ugly captcha's on it, unless it's absolutely necessary.

So you let the user submit the form, and if the same user submits the form again show the captcha, or whatever.

Is it possible to detect if the 2nd form submission comes from the same user?

I know about `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ATTR']` (which is the user IP), but is this reliable? Since this variable stores a value that is sent by the user, I guess any bot can fake that, right?

Comment: Why not use sessions/cookies? "Detecting" a specific person or browser will always be inherently flawed using data sent by the browser.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ATTR']` is not sent by the browser. It's the address your web server is addressing HTTP packets to. Unfortunately it can't work as identifier for you because many users can be hidden behind 1 IP address via NAT (plus other disadvantages). You'll have to stick to session cookies.

Comment: Actually I don't think sessions/cookies will help because most likely spam bots won't be keeping and sending your cookies back so they'll be able to submit as many times as they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go 2 routes.  You can either use a rolling csrf token or store a flag in session.  The session flag is a bit more straight forward:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['submit_flag'])){
   $_SESSION['submit_flag']=true
   //perform action...
}
```